# How can I create a Rust Clippy binary to use as part of a separate standalone application?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, dylib, rustup, rust-clippy

I am trying to build a standalone application through which I can run Rust Clippy without needing to install it locally. Essentially, I want to run a command like `cargo-clippy -- --message-format=json` through my application when a Rust project is uploaded to it.

What I've tried:

- I installed `cargo` locally using the instructions [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/getting-started/installation.html)
- I forked the Clippy repo locally into a folder called `clippy_local`
- I ran `cargo build` on the repo which created some exe binary files including `cargo-clippy` under `clippy_local/target/debug/` (contents of the `target` folder attached in screenshot below)
  [image: Contents of Clippy target folder]
- I copied this `cargo-clippy` exe into the tool binaries folder for my application

After this, the project compiles, but when I try to run Clippy through my tool, I get an error like below:

```
dyld[14510]: Library not loaded: '@rpath/librustc_driver-6ca1b5240144bf0b.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/<redacted>/repos/<redacted>/target/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/tools/clippy/cargo-clippy'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/librustc_driver-6ca1b5240144bf0b.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/librustc_driver-6ca1b5240144bf0b.dylib' (no such file)
```

My app is running the following command internally to invoke Clippy:

```
/Users/<redacted>/repos/<redacted>/target/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/tools/clippy/cargo-clippy -- --message-format=json
```

I was guessing from the error that it has something to do with missing libraries/dependencies (apart from the `cargo-clippy` exe). I have tried to copy all the contents of the `target/debug` folder into my app as well, but the same error still persists.

So, I want to know what's going wrong and how I can build a Rust Clippy binary which I can then use to run Clippy from other applications?

Comment: You should probably also copy some of the other files (and folders) in the same folder, such as clippy-driver